# Why won't this create a new line in a text file in Android?

Tags: java, android, file

This is a method in my Android app that should create a new line in the text file before a new String text is added. However, when it runs, There is no new line.

```
    public void addTextToFile(String text) {
    try
    {
        File log=new File(getFilesDir()+File.separator+"MileageLog.txt");

        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=null;
        if(log.exists()==false)
        {
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(log+"\n"));


        }else{
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(log+"\n", true));

        }
        String[] lines=text.split("\n");
        for(String line:lines)
        {
            bufferedWriter.write(line);

        }
        bufferedWriter.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }catch(IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not writing new line character (*you are actually splitting text by new line character so there is no new line character in your `lines`*)

change it to

```
bufferedWriter.write(line);
bufferedWriter.newLine();
```

if you want to add new line after each line

Comment: Please note that this will result in a `StringBuilder` allocation, which is more expensive than when it just writes `line` and then `\n`. Therefore using `.newLine()` as mentioned above or wrapping it in a `PrintWriter` and using `.println()` might be cheaper (possibly ignoring synchronization).

Comment: @Stack agreed, fixed answer

Comment: It's only a very minor problem in most cases, trading verbosity for efficiency. I just wanted to point it out. :)

Comment: or just wrap `BufferedWriter` with `PrintWriter` and use `println(line)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the newLine() method that will write a line separator. For further details, check the link: [Android BufferedWriter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine%28%29)